# Positivity of the Fourier transform of a certain function

Tags: calculus, analysis, fourier-analysis

I am trying to show that the Fourier transform of $\cosh(x)^{-\nu}$ is positive for every $\nu>1$. 
I know that such a function has even Fourier transform and... that's about it. Could you suggets a way to attack this problem?

Thanks.

PS: the positivity is ensured by some piece of advanced theory, but I would like to prove it by getting my hands "dirty", although it seems rather difficult.

Comment: Have you tried to analyze $\int_{0}^{\infty}\cosh(x)^{-\nu}\cos(sx)dx$ as an alternating series? You end up only have to consider the first few 1/2 cycles of $x\mapsto \cos(sx)$ for $s > 0$ to know the ultimate sign of the alternatively series.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, it seems that this is a well-known formula one can easily find in integral tables! See e.g. Gradshtein and Ryzhik, formula 3.985.1. Thanks anyway for your answer! :)